# AppEngine Google Apps Authentication: Can you switch domains?

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication

I've set up an AppEngine account using Google Apps Authentication and I've resigned myself to the fact that it [can't be changed](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/auth). But can you switch the domain that it's bound to?

**UPDATE**
Forgot one point. We've already added users from the new domain as AppEngine administrators and we're able to log into the AppEngine console with them. But there are certain URLs in the app itself (e.g. cron jobs/task queues) that we've restricted to access by admins only. When we try to access them, we are directed to the domain-specific AppEngine page (i.e. http://appengine.google.com/a/myolddomain.com) to log in.  When I update the URL to the new domain, I can log in but then I get a page saying "The page is requesting permission to access your Google account. Select an account you would like to use." And there are no options in the list to select. I can click Continue but then I'm redirected back to the login page for the old domain again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If you created an app with Google Apps authentication, it is tied to that domain to authenticate against forever. This only matters if you're using the Users API, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can switch to another domain. App Engine is a service in your apps domain. Because it is a service, I think you can add the same appspot service to multiple apps domains.

Comment: I forgot to clarify where we're running into trouble. Question has been updated.

Comment: Do you pay for your domains? Google Apps support is very helpfull.

Comment: Yes we do but I haven't been able to find out how to contact support. Usually just get redirected to the Google Groups site. Any tips?

Comment: The is a support menu in your management console of the apps domain. There you can find the Customer and Support Pin and the contact options.

Comment: This doesn't really apply - this is an App Engine question, not an Apps question.